# Как сделать проверку email и телефона

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, form

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку правильности написания email и телефона, пока сделал проверку на ненаполненность полей, но хотелось бы проверить правильность. И не могу подсветить textarea почему то таким же способом как input ((
Спасибо.

```js
$("#sendMail").on("click", function () {



    //создаем экземпляр класс FormData, тут будем хранить всю информацию для отправки

    var formData = new FormData();



    //присоединяем наш файл

    jQuery.each($('#file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {

        formData.append('file_v', file);

    });



    //присоединяем остальные поля

    let name = $("#name").val().trim();

    let email = $("#email").val().trim();

    let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();

    let number_order = $("#number_order").val().trim();

    let message = $("#message").val().trim();

    let checkbox_check = $("#checkbox_check").prop('checked');



    //проверяем поля на заполнение

    if (name === '' || email === '' || tel === '' || number_order === '' || message === '' || !checkbox_check) {

        $('.modal_error').show();

        $.each($('.input-box input'),function(i, v){

            if($(this).val() == ''){

                $(this).addClass('empty_field');

            }else{

                $(this).removeClass('empty_field');

            }

        });

        return false;

    }



    formData.append('name', name);

    formData.append('email', email);

    formData.append('tel', tel);

    formData.append('number_order', number_order);

    formData.append('message', message);





    //отправляем через ajax

    $.ajax({

        url: "assets/ajax/mail.php",

        type: "POST",

        dataType : "json",

        cache: false,

        contentType: false,

        processData: false,

        data: formData, //указываем что отправляем

        beforeSend: function () {

            $("#form_contact").prop("disable", true);

            $(".main-btn").attr("disabled", true);

            $( ".loading_mail").show();



        },

        success: function(data){

            //стереть данные из инпутов

            $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");

            /////////////**********////////////

            //убрать загрузачное окно

            $( ".loading_mail").hide();

            ////////////**********//////////////

            //убрать подсветку

            $('.input-box input').removeClass('empty_field');

            $(".main-btn").attr("disabled", false);

            $('.modal_success').show();

            console.log(data);

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

```css
.checkbox {



}



.checkbox__input {

  display: none;

}



.checkbox__input:checked + .checkbox__label::after {

  transform: scale(1);

}



.checkbox__label {

  font-size: 16px;

  line-height: 140%;

  display: inline-flex;

  align-items: center;

  position: relative;

  cursor: pointer;

}



.checkbox__label::before {

  content: "";

  align-self: flex-start;

  flex: 0 0 24px;

  height: 24px;

  background: #dcdce8;

  border-radius: 4px;

  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;



}





.checkbox__label::after {

  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;

  content: "";

  width: 16px;

  height: 16px;

  position: absolute;

  top: 4px;

  left: 4px;

  background: #f07d54;

  border-radius: 4px;

  transform: scale(0);

}





.checkbox__label a {

  color: #f07d54;

}





/*  Загрузка отправки формы обратной связи  */



.comment-form {

  position: relative;

}



.loading_mail{

  content: "";

  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  left: 0;

  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9) url(loading.gif) center / 50px no-repeat;

  display: none;

}





.input-box input.empty_field {

  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;

}



/* Custom dropdown */



/* Стили для неактивного модального окна */





/* стилизация содержимого страницы */





/* свойства модального окна по умолчанию */



   /* свойства модального окна по умолчанию */

 .modal {

   position: fixed;

   /* фиксированное положение */

   top: 0;

   right: 0;

   bottom: 0;

   left: 0;

   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

   /* цвет фона */

   z-index: 1050;

   /*opacity: 0;*/

   /* по умолчанию модальное окно прозрачно */

   -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;

   -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;

   transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;

   /* анимация перехода */

   pointer-events: none;

   /* элемент невидим для событий мыши */

 }

/* при отображении модального окно */

.modal:target {

  /*opacity: 1;*/

  pointer-events: auto;

  overflow-y: auto;

}

/* ширина модального окна и его отступы от экрана */

.modal-dialog {

  position: relative;

  width: auto;

  margin: 10px;

}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .modal-dialog {

    max-width: 500px;

    margin: 30px auto;

  }

}

/* свойства для блока, содержащего контент модального окна */

.modal-content {

  position: relative;

  display: -webkit-box;

  display: -webkit-flex;

  display: -ms-flexbox;

  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

  -webkit-box-direction: normal;

  -webkit-flex-direction: column;

  -ms-flex-direction: column;

  flex-direction: column;

  background-color: #fff;

  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;

  background-clip: padding-box;

  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

  border-radius: .3rem;

  outline: 0;

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .modal-content {

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

  }

}

/* свойства для заголовка модального окна */

.modal-header {

  display: -webkit-box;

  display: -webkit-flex;

  display: -ms-flexbox;

  display: flex;

  -webkit-box-align: center;

  -webkit-align-items: center;

  -ms-flex-align: center;

  align-items: center;

  -webkit-box-pack: justify;

  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;

  -ms-flex-pack: justify;

  justify-content: space-between;

  padding: 15px;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #eceeef;

}

.modal-title {

  margin-top: 0;

  margin-bottom: 0;

  line-height: 1.5;

  font-size: 1.25rem;

  font-weight: 500;

}

/* свойства для кнопки "Закрыть" */

.close {

  float: right;

  font-family: sans-serif;

  font-size: 24px;

  font-weight: 700;

  line-height: 1;

  color: #000;

  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;

  /*opacity: .5;*/

  text-decoration: none;

}

/* свойства для кнопки "Закрыть" при нахождении её в фокусе или наведении */

.close:focus,

.close:hover {

  color: #000;

  text-decoration: none;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: .75;

}

/* свойства для блока, содержащего основное содержимое окна */

.modal-body {

  position: relative;

  -webkit-box-flex: 1;

  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;

  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;

  flex: 1 1 auto;

  padding: 15px;

  overflow: auto;

}



#openModal-error {

  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);

}



#openModal-success {

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <form id="form_contact" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-one__form">  <!---->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box has-feedback nameBlock">
                                        <label for="name" class="control-label ">Имя*</label>
                                        <input required type="text" id="name" placeholder="Иван Иванов" name="name" value="" class="" >
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email-адрес*</label>
                                        <input required type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box _req">
                                        <label for="tel" class="control-label">Номер телефона*</label>
                                        <input required type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="+79997772255" name="tel" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="number_order" class="control-label">№ заказа*</label>
                                        <input required id="number_order" type="text" placeholder="0000000-я00" name="number_order" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="message" class="control-label">Сообщение*</label>
                                        <textarea required class="_req" id="message" name="message"
                                        placeholder="Сообщение" class="">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="file">
                                        <div class="file__item">
                                            <input type=file id="file_v" name="file_v" accept="image/*,video/*" class="file__input">
                                            <div class="file__button">Прикрепить файл</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="formPreview" class="file__preview"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input required id="checkbox_check" checked type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox__input">
                                        <label for="checkbox_check" class="checkbox__label _error"><span>Я даю согласие на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="">Условиями</a>*</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                                    <br>
                                    <button  id="sendMail" class="main-btn"> Отправить </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Телефон несложно проверяется регуляркой. А вот проверка email с учётом всех вывертов RFC - задача весьма нетривиальная. Впрочем, и то, и другое не раз обсуждалось - воспользуйтесь поиском. что ли...

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой замечательный аттрибут `pattern` нужно конечно убедится что браузер его поддерживает.

```html
<input type="email" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в js проверку можно сделать так как указано ниже

проверка почты:

```
let email = $("#email").val().trim();

function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

if (!isEmail(email)){
  return false;       //  выход их функции отправки формы
}
```

проверка телефона:

```
let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();

function telephoneCheck(str) {
  var regex = /^(1\s?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s\-]?\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{4}$/;
  return regex.test(str);
}

if (!telephoneCheck(tel)){
  return false
}
```

C учетом рефакторинга можно было бы сделать что-то в этом роде:

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

function telephoneCheck(str) {
  var regex = /^(1\s?)?(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[\s\-]?\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{4}$/;
  return regex.test(str);
}

function getValidationErrors = (fields) => {
    let errors = []; // массив для ошибок

    const {email, tel, ...otherFields} = fields; // извлекаем поля

    // к телефону и почте так же можно добавить свои классы ошибок 
    if (!isEmail(email)) errors.push('email');
    if (!telephoneCheck(tel)) errors.push('tel');

    Object.entries(otherFields).forEach(entry => {
        const {key, value} = entry;
        if (!value){
            errors.push(key);
            $(`#${key}.input-box input`).addClass('empty_field');
        } else {
           $(`#${key}.input-box input`).removeClass('empty_field'); 
        }
    })
    return errors;
}

$("#sendMail").on("click", function () {
    //создаем экземпляр класс FormData, тут будем хранить всю информацию для отправки
    const formData = new FormData();
    //присоединяем наш файл
    jQuery.each($('#file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append('file_v', file);
    });

    //присоединяем остальные поля
    const name = $("#name").val().trim();
    const email = $("#email").val().trim();
    const tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
    const number_order = $("#number_order").val().trim();
    const message = $("#message").val().trim();
    const checkbox_check = $("#checkbox_check").prop('checked');

    // все поля кроме чекбокса так как его не отправляем 
    const fields = {name, email, tel, number_order, message};

    //проверяем поля 
    if (getValidationErrors({...fields, checkbox_check}).length !== 0){
        $('.modal_error').show();
        return false;
    }
    
    // добавляем поля в форму отправки
    Object.entries(fields).forEach(({key, value}) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    })
    
    //отправляем через ajax
});
```

Comment: Нужна проверка в js, в html  эта штука не работает у меня.

Comment: @Sirius_MkLain не подсвечивается так поле?

Comment: нет, не подсвечивается

Comment: @Sirius_MkLain добавил фрагмент кода, по хорошему конечно нужно подписывать где ошибки или подсвечивать

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло))

Comment: вообще лучше разделить код и вынести валидацию отдельно с возвратом объекта ключи которого будут иметь ошибки соответсвующих полей, если ключей нет значит можно отсылать - реализовать это можно разными способами

Comment: --@banana.ru - пройдет? А admin@longest.domains?

Comment: пройдет, регулярки тут не самые сильные, они бывают очень удивительной длинны если нужна точность.